# Creating application release which involves wx-widget

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets, rebar

I am trying to generate an application realease which uses wx widgets.
The program compiles and runs fine on my PC. when i move the distribution to another PC it shows errors telling i should run the erlang with smp enabled. 
On the compiling machine the erlang distribution does have smp enabled by default but i cant see why this matters to the generated distribution its it the idea of compiling a stand alone version of the erlang application?

on the reltool.config file i added the **rel** and **app** this doesnt matter.

also i tried manually adding the -smp falg on the **vm.args** files.

any other ideas?

Comment: Can you add your config file? Wx does indeed require smp to be enabled, but its not clear to me why it isn't from what you wrote above.